# update table with SQL function

Tags: sql-server, oracle, function, updating

I would like to update data in a table (for sqlserver and oralce version).

I created a stored procedure as below, but i would like to convert it to SQL function, is it possible to update data within SQL function please?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updatetable (@A1 INTEGER, @A2 VARCHAR(4000) )
AS
  BEGIN
        BEGIN
            UPDATE table SET column1= column1+ @A1 WHERE column2= @A2 ;
        END    
  END
```

Comment: Why does this need to be a function? Why is the procedure insufficient?

Comment: From Oracle perspective, technically yes, but should not be done and procedure should be used, rather for DMLs. Refer - https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=function-with-dml-ddl

Comment: Wanting to convert to a function (and slightly guessing what you mean by a 'SQL function') suggests you want to be able to call the function as part of a query. Oracle [won't let you do that](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adfns/coding-subprograms-and-packages.html#GUID-035E5BD6-A547-4E88-9C41-52575A4298FE) either (really gross and dangerous hacks aside *8-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For SQL Server.*

Simply put:

#### No.

A function can't change the system (really gross and dangerous hacks aside). From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql) (emphasis mine):

> Specifies that a series of Transact-SQL statements, which together do not produce a side effect ***such as modifying a table***

If you can explain what you're trying to accomplish with a function that you can't accomplish with a stored procedure, you might be asking a question that has more than a yes/no answer, and you might get useful alternatives.

Comment: I just wanted to know if it is possible to convert it into a function, but it seems that it is not possible so I keep the stored procedure.Thanks a lot for details